# Selecting a specific form content

Tags: javascript, html, html5

This code is used for displaying only certain content of the form instead of displaying all the form content. I am using it to stop the users from filling all the form fields if those are irrelevant to the user.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
var delivery_div = document.getElementById('delivery');
var delivery_div1 = document.getElementById('delivery1');
checkbox.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this);
  if (this.checked) {
    delivery_div.style['display'] = 'block';
  } else {
    delivery_div.style['display'] = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked = false;
  delivery_div1.style['display'] = 'none';
};
checkbox1.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this);
  if (this.checked) {
    delivery_div1.style['display'] = 'block';
  } else {
    delivery_div1.style['display'] = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;
  delivery_div.style['display'] = 'none';
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  check any checkbox
  1<input id="checkbox" type=checkbox name=check>
  2<input id="checkbox1" type=checkbox name=check>
</div>

<div id="delivery" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    certain form content is shown
  </div>
</div>
<div id="delivery1" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    different from above form content is shown
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In both of the `.onclick` functions, you have a line like this:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked = false;
```

Why are you trying to find the element `"checkbox1"` again if you already have a variable stored with this element at the above of your code?

It would be a lot more efficient to just use this variable, because

1. You already made it, so you might as well use it.
2. You don't have to call `document.getElementById` again.

---

Your two `onclick` methods look very, very similar. The only difference? Which element it is that you are using.

Therefore, you should create a single, separate function that takes the element(s) that need to be changed. Then, you can just set the two `onclick` methods to calls of this separate function.

Here is what I wrote for that function:

```
function displayContent(changeElement, uncheckElement, deliveryElement) {
    var self = changeElement;
    console.log(self);
    if(self.checked) {
        deliveryElement.style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
        deliveryElement.style['display'] = 'none';
    }
    uncheckElement.checked = false;
    self.style['display'] = 'none';
}
```

Now, for example, the `onclick` of `checkbox` will look like this:

```
checkbox.onclick = function() {
    displayContent(checkbox, checkbox1, delivery_div);
}
```

---

These lines:

```
if (this.checked) {
    delivery_div1.style['display'] = 'block';
} else {
    delivery_div1.style['display'] = 'none';
}
```

can be shortened.

First off, you should be setting the new value of display separately. Then, you can create a simple and small ternary to set the `'display'` style property of `delivery_div1` to that new value.

Here is what that looks like:

```
var display = (this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
delivery_div1.style['display'] = display;
```

See how this works? The ternary is checking the same exact thing that the `if/else` was doing, only this time it's only setting `display`. Then, after the ternary, the style `display` property is set.